# Floating and clearing this div layout

Tags: html, css

I have two  menus floated to the left of a page.
I then have a div floated to the right with an auto height, that adjusts to the content on the page (results of the menu ).

In my example I will treat the ul's as divs since they are set to block elements anyway:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div1_head"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2_head"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
        <div class="div3_head"></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Each of these elements has a separate div header that goes above them.

I cannot figure out the correct way (if there is one) to clear and float the divs, so that they will all be aligned in the correct row.

```
margin:0;
 padding:0;
 .container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}
.div1_head {
    float:left;
    background: #cfcfcf;
    width:20%;
    height:50px;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}
.div1 {
    float:left;
    background: #dedede;
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    clear:left
}
.div2_head {
    float:left;
    background: #cfcfcf;
    width:20%;
    height:50px;
    clear:left;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}
.div2 {
    float:left;
    background: #dedede;
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    clear:left
}
.div3_head {
    float:right;
    background: #cfcfcf;
    width:76%;
    height:50px;
    clear:none;
    margin: 0 0 0 4%;
}
.div3 {
    float:right;
    background: #dedede;
    width:76%;
    height:200px;
    clear:none;
    margin: 0 0 0 4%;
}
```

Do to the nature of the web application i'm using nesting the div and header into a larger container div isn't an option.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kq49s/1/

Comment: What you're asking for WILL require nesting.  The fact that your "web application" doesn't allow for it will just over complicate things.  The correct way to handle what you're trying to achieve is to wrap each column into it's own container that is floated.

Comment: Arg I was afraid of that, nesting is currently being implemented into the web-app I am using, so I will just have to hold off for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you don't want to add in new DIVs to your current app.

Try to change your div3's css like this...

Here is the demo on jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/NTX6h/

```
.div3_head {
    position:absolute;
    top:24px;     /* same as your .div1_head's margin top */
    right:10px;   /* if you want to add some right margin */
    background: #cfcfcf;
    width:76%;
    height:50px;
}
.div3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:74px;     /* .div3_head's margin top + .div3_head's height  */
    right:10px;   /* if you want to add some right margin */
    background: #dedede;
    width:76%;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Ah this should work for the time being, i'm pretty stubborn about using absolute positioning, but at least i can get it looking correct for now.